# Canvas reference lost when resizing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dom-events

I've got a Grid "class" that listens to resize events on window and calls a function, which right now is simply logging a reference to a DOM element. Accessing the el before resize works perfectly, and it works the same way after, but during my resize event callback, it's undefined. What gives?

```
function Grid (el) {
  this.el = document.querySelector(el);
  this.init();
}

Grid.prototype.init = function() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeCanvas, false);
}

Grid.prototype.resizeCanvas = function() {
  console.log(this.el);
}
```

Whenever I resize browser, undefined is logged.

Comment: This happens because `this` in `window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeCanvas, false);` refers to the `window` object, and not the `Grid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resizeCanvas is not being called with Grid's context. One option would be to do something like this instead:

```
Grid.prototype.init = function() {
  var self = this;
  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    self.resizeCanvas();
  }, false);
}
```